Missing symbols for libraries when attempting to perform analysing of core dump
I'm trying to analyze core dump files of the systemd process, but encountering errors due to missing symbols.
Can anyone advise what debug symbols need to be installed to successfully analyze these core dumps?
gdb  -e /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald -c core-systemd-journal--0-0-657-1718434887
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2-20.el8
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 657]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libuuid.so.1
Try: yum --enablerepo='*debug*' install /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/d0/43572678e11cfb56aecb4ec534bc016de8d0d5.debug
Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libudev.so.1
Try: yum --enablerepo='*debug*' install /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/94/5e15d6b231fc346823186cd70e886dede771ca.debug
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.


so, did you try what you recommended to try in the output?

I have tried running the follow as suggested yum --enablerepo='*debug*' install /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/94/5e15d6b231fc346823186cd70e886dede771ca.debug. I get the following instead No match for argument: /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/d0/43572678e11cfb56aecb4ec534bc016de8d0d5.debug Error: Unable to find a match: /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/d0/43572678e11cfb56aecb4ec534bc016de8d0d5.debug. Normally, I would obtain the relevant symbols through dnf debuginfo-install <package>. However, I am not sure where to get the ones listed in the output.

Release version (--releasever=8.9) is important as the current version is now at 8.10 and dnf will default to this release.
Ran the dnf to list what provides the symbol
sudo dnf --releasever=8.9 --enablerepo='*debug*' provides /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/d0/43572678e11cfb56aecb4ec534bc016de8d0d5.debug /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/94/5e15d6b231fc346823186cd70e886dede771ca.debug

Repo        : baseos-debuginfo
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/d0/43572678e11cfb56aecb4ec534bc016de8d0d5.debug

And then installed the required package:
sudo dnf --releasever=8.9 install libuuid-debuginfo-2.32.1-44.el8_9.1.x86_64

Reference: https://forums.almalinux.org/t/missing-symbols-for-libraries-when-attempting-to-perform-analysing-of-core-cump/4251/5
